# File upload jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, jersey

I create jersey REST server and receive file upload.
This is the tutorial I follwed: https://gist.github.com/aitoroses/4f7a2b197b732a6a691d

Everything works fine when I try to test the server with Postman. I chose Body, form-data, key: file, value: my picture jpeg

What I try to do is to upload file using form html and jquery
Here is my form

```
<form>
<input id="imgFile" type="file" accept="image/*" value="Add file">
                    <input id="buttonPostReview" class="buttonSend" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and here is my jquery

```
var postFile = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var imgFile = $('#imgFile').val();
  var upLoalImgUrl = endPointUrl + 'webresources/photo';
  console.log(imgFile);
  console.log('uploading..');

  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: upLoalImgUrl,
            data: imgFile,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false,
            success: function (returnData) {
              console.log(returnData);
              alert("Data Uploaded: ");
            }
        });
}
```

But I got error 415 - Unsupported Media Type
Can you show me how to upload file using jquery? I try to do some search but I can find the way to do this

Comment: That is not how you upload a file with Ajax...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$(...).val()` doesn't get a file from a file input, it just returns the name of the file. You need to do `$("#imgFile")[0].files[0]` and send the file with [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('file', $("#imgFile")[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({ data: data, ... });
```

Comment: That's not  how you add items to FormData object

Comment: Right, forgot my syntax for a sec. Better?

Comment: So how I do it the right way? I follow your way and I got code 400 bad request

Comment: var data = new FormData();
  var file = $("#imgFile")[0].files[0];
  data.append('file', file);

Comment: This is the right solution for me

Comment: The post should be edited to the correct code. Your snippet seems to be equivalent to my post.